# Showing that an increase in uncertainty is significant

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, uncertainty, error-propagation

I have a linear model $y = ax+b$ and I estimate the coefficients $a$ and $b$ in the ordinary way.

I have found out that all of my values of $x$ were systematically overestimated, and also that they have known uncertainties that were heretofore not propagated.

Using total least squares (Deming regression), I find new estimates $\tilde a$ and $\tilde b$. These estimates have a much larger uncertainty ($15\%$ greater), but overlap with the previous estimates of $a$ and $b$.

Since the distributions of the estimates overlap, a referee has said that the change is not significant, and has asked me if I can show that the increase in uncertainty is significant. How can I determine this?

Also, due to regression dilution, the estimated central value of $\tilde a$ is larger than $a$. Is there a one-sided test I can use to show that the means are different, even if their distributions overlap?

Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So this is an instance where there are errors in variables. Deming regression addresses the problem.  I assume by the ordinary way you mean ordinary least squares.  Least squares takes the residuals only in the y direction.  Error in variables regression takes the residuals in a different direction. If the variation in x (due to measurement error is the same as for y you minimizes the square of residuals in a direction perpendicular to the line.  I think the referee has the idea that you can ignore the problem if the variance in y dominates the error in x.

Comment: It seems to me that if the error is only in the negative direction I would think that the slope estimate a would be smaller than for ordinary least squares (all the true values of x are lower than given in the recorded data).

Comment: I now think that error in variables such as Deming regression may not be appropriate because such methods assume an average error of 0 for the x's.

Comment: @MichaelChernick What errors in variables model would you suggest? Note also that the errors are correlated.

Comment: What did you mean by "known uncertainties"? Should I assume that the values cannot be corrected because if they could you would do that first?

Comment: @MichaelChernick yes that's right. Let's say the values are $x$ are measured with a ruler and we know the precision of the ruler, so we know the uncertainty on $x$. I found that people weren't "zeroing out" the ruler, so all the $x$ values are really $x + dx$ where $dx$ depends on $x$.